# Determine which ASP.NET button was clicked using Javascript

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript, client-side

What is the best way to determine which ASP.NET button was clicked on a single page using JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just the set the OnClientClick event handler for the button with the JavaScript function I wanted executed when the button was clicked during the Page_Load event.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventsArgs e)
{
    MyButton.OnClientClick = "MyJavaScriptMethod();";
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Add a client-side onclick handler to each button pointing to the same function?

e.g.

```
<button onclick="myHandler(this.ID)" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily add a client side Javascript click handler to an ASP button like this.

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "alert('You clicked me!');");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(btnDelSentMailMulti, this.GetType(), "script", "alert('Exchange password is empty.Please check.');", true);
```

Call this code in .cs of your aspx page. Replace with your values.